# Record cloning - php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to duplicate a row on table `about`, I have tried:

```
$sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tbl SELECT * FROM about WHERE id = '" . ($id) . "' ";
$sql .= "SELECT @maxId := MAX(id) + 1 FROM about; ";
$sql .= "UPDATE temp_tbl SET id = @maxId; ";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO about SELECT * FROM temp_tbl ";
$sql .= "DROP TABLE temp_tbl";

$result = $database->query($sql);
```

but I have `Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to look into the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax.

Comment: And in future, tell us the FULL and COMPLETE error message, not a summary

Comment: You are trying to execute multiple queries in one go. You need to execute them one after another

Comment: You cannot execute multiple queries using `->query()` even if they were all syntactically correct

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: This is really `INSERT INTO about (id) SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM about`. Are you trying to implement a sequence generator? Your existing code has a race condition. The single `INSERT` version does not.